# Selenium TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, typeerror

I'm trying to automate giftcard input on amazon, and I made this code

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
    import time
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?clientContext=131-4641921-7497613&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgc%2Fredeem%2F&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_gcfront_v2_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&marketPlaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&pageId=amzn_gcfront_v2_us&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=3600&siteState=clientContext%3D144-1807701-9645427%2CsourceUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.amazon.com%252Fgc%252Fredeem%252F%2Csignature%3DduV3UfJbYbHeREFcPDmzxQt6fpIj3D")
    usr = driver.find_element_by_id("ap_email")
    usr.clear()
    usr.send_keys("username/email")
    pwd = driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password")
    pwd.clear()
    pwd.send_keys("pass")
    pwd.submit()
    
    #after email confirmation

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password"))
    pwd = driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password")
    pwd.clear()
    pwd.send_keys("pass")
    pwd.submit()
    
    for i in range(1000):
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/gc/redeem/")
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("gc-redemption-input")
        elem.clear()
        code_file = open("file directory", "r")
        code = code_file.readlines()
        code_file.close()
        elem.send_keys(code[i])
        elem.submit()
```

but I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AutoSubmitGiftcardAmazon.py", line 20, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 77, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable
```

I want this code to wait for me to confirm my email and then fill the password automatically
pls help

Edit :
I changed the

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password"))
```

to

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, "ap_password"))
```

and I've imported

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as ec
```

and I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AutoSubmitGiftcardAmazon.py", line 22, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, "ap_password"))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I'm a beginner, pls help me

Comment: You're not calling `.until()` correctly.  It doesn't take a plain element as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

The above error very clear, appear because you need takes 3 positional arguments.

Try this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ap_password")))
```

[Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)